# How can I compare tables and display if records don't exist?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I want to compare the two tables which are the studentvotes and student.
[image: Image of my data structures]

I would like to display the 'idno' of the 'student' that who doesn't exist in table 'studentvotes' but I will based it on the 'syearid'. For example, 'idno' like 'c23' then votes in the year 2015. But not voted in 2016 the 'idno' will display that 'c23' didn't vote for the year 2016. How can I do that?

Here are some details: I can display who are already voted by  year but I don't know how to display student who didn't vote by year that's only my problem right now.

Here's what I've done:

```
 $stud = mysql_query("select * from student,studentvotes where student.idno = studenvotes.idno AND student.syearid = studentvotes.syearid AND studentvotes.syearid = '$no'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I think this should work:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN studentvotes sv 
    ON st.idno = sv.idno AND st.syearid = sv.syearid
WHERE sv.idno IS NULL
```

Comment: sir, what if the student registered in year 2015 when I voted in 2017, then it will not display because who didn't vote because student registered in 2015 not 2017

Comment: @miming can you create http://sqlfiddle.com with your data, so I could check this out, please

Answer (score 0):

Filter data based on the `syearid` and discard records which are not present in `student votes` using `not in clause`

```
select st.* from students st 
where st.idno not in (select  idno  from studentvotes  where syearid=2015 ) and st.syearid=2015
```